# SQL Server Database ODBC User List

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to get a list of ODBC users on a SQL Server database? I can see them using SSMS; but would like get a report for the management.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily fetch those using a query something like this:

```
SELECT 
   name, principal_id, default_schema_name, create_date  -- more columns available
FROM sys.database_principals
WHERE type = 'S'  -- SQL Server users
   OR type = 'W'  -- Windows users
```

Comment: Thank you! I got a list that I can share. Appreciate your help!